# Gremlin query to get vertices starting with a prefix

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to fetch vertices that start with a specific prefixes in JAVA. I have used the between predicate. Is there a better way to do the same.
For example if I need the vertices starting with 'a'. I would use

`.has(label, propertyKey, P.between("a", "b"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the release of TinkerPop 3.4.0, Gremlin also supports simple text predicates

In this case, you should use `startingWith`.

```
.has(label, propertyKey, TextP.startingWith("a"))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/ad